# Print values of single column into d/f column based on comma

Tags: python, loops

I am working on a csv file and a column consist of one to multiple  integer value which is comma separated. Firstly, the code will be able to know the maximum values in rows based on comma. After that it will generate the column with name a/c to the maximum value. Finally, it will be able to print values in the new columns. I am working on a big data.

```
INPUT
col  column-name vvs
x12  2,3,4       ab
d3   4           fd
3fd  2,5,8,6     cf
5r4  3,2         mg
```

Following is the code which I try to write

```
a=read_file("xyz.csv") #READ FILE IS A FUNCTION AND IT WORKS PROPERLY
print(a["column-name"].max())
def dfmax(dfcl):
    cl=0
    t=[]
    for i in range(dfcl.size):
        b=dfcl[i]
        c=b.split(",")
        if len(c) > cl :
            cl=len(c)
            t=b
    print(cl)
    print(t)
    return cl

c=dfmax(a["column-name"])
print(c)


for i in range(c):
        a.insert(5+i,"A"+str(i+1),a["column-name"],True) #CODE IS WORKING FINE TILL HERE IT IS PRINTING MAXIMUM LENGTH
#I assume just to check the code that the maximum values in the column 5
c=5
#for i in range(a["column-name"].size):
for i in range(20):
    b=a["column-name"][i]
    cb=b.split(",")
    for j in range(c):
        if j < len(cb):
            st = "A"+str(j+1)
            #print(st)
            a[st][i]=cb[j]
        else:
            a[st][i]=""

  DESIRED OUTPUT
    col  column-name column-name-2 column-name-3 column-name-4  vvs
    x12  2           3             4                            ab
    d3   4                                                      fd
    3fd  2           5             8             6              cf
    5r4  3           2                                          mg
```

Unfortunately, code is not working properly. It provides below error. If there is a simpler way to do this task kindly let me know.

```
C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:10: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  # Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.
C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:12: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if sys.path[0] == '':
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of using pandas to load your data from .csv and creating the desired output. I used np.nan to fill the blank spots with "empty" data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r"<PATH TO YOUR CSV>")
for row, item in enumerate(df["column-name"]):
    l = item.split(",")
    for idx, elem in enumerate(l):
        col = "column-name-%s" % idx
        if col not in df.columns:
            df[col] = np.nan
        df[col][row] = elem

df = df.drop(columns=["column-name"])

print(df)
```

Here we first go over all rows in our dataframe for column "column-name" to get the comma seperated values and there row number. After that we split it to get a list of all numbers in that cell.
Now we go over our list and remember at which position the number was (idx) so we know in which column it belongs. Now that we know the column we check if it already exists. If it exists we just add our value to the corresponding row. Otherwise we create a new column and fill it with empty data first.

This then gives us the following output:

```
   col vvs  column-name-0  column-name-1  column-name-2  column-name-3
0  x12  ab            2.0            3.0            4.0            NaN
1   d3  fd            4.0            NaN            NaN            NaN
2  3fd  cf            2.0            5.0            8.0            6.0
3  5r4  mg            3.0            2.0            NaN            NaN
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The code is working perfectly. The only issue is that I want to add the new columns next to the first column and the code is adding column at the end.  I try to solve it by myself but unfortunately I didn't solve it on my own. Moreover, it is printing the result with this error C:\Users\********\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2903: DtypeWarning: